# Java socket program support

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

Hello I was doing a chat program in Java but then I came up with and idee, I wanted to make commands. For an example the Server write "date" and then it will return the clients time and date!

In the code I have write:`while(!streamChat.equals("CLIENT - END"));`
It will close the Stream or the socket but I cant make a if statemend so it can read wich command it is and what it should do plz help me.

Here is my code:

```
        do{
        try{
            streamChat = (String) inputdata.readObject();       //Reading the object.. and storing it in a variable...
            showMess("\n " + streamChat);

        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
             //catching the errors... 
        }

    }while(!streamChat.equals("CLIENT - END"));     //The ending
```

Comment: I dont now where to put the if statement... ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is simple. You just write:

```
try{
      streamChat = (String) inputdata.readObject();     //Reading the object.. and storing it in a variable...
      if(//your statement here){
             //Your command action here
          }         
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is bit unclear your question, but I guess you need to read socket until specific String reads.

Try this one

```
streamChat = (String) inputdata.readObject();
while (!streamChat.equals("CLIENT - END")) {

    try {
        showMess("\n " + streamChat);
        streamChat = (String) inputdata.readObject();      


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
        //catching the errors... 
    }

}

closeSocket();
```